# Why mysqli_real_escape_string() returns NULL?

Tags: php, mysqli, null, escaping

I am coding a login/register page.
I want to protect the form from sql injections using `mysqli_real_escape_string()`.
If I use it, the function returns `NULL`.

And I don't know why...
I searched and I found that maybe I am not connected to the database, but I am since I can query it .

This is the code that I am using to connect to the database (db.php):

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost","user","pass","database");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
?>
```

The code that returns NULL:

```
include("includes/db.php");
function escapeInput($data) {
    $data = trim($data);
    $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
    $data = stripslashes($data);
    $data = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $data);
    return $data;
}
if (isset($_SESSION['username'])){
    header("Location: home.php");
}
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{
    if($_POST['action'] == 'login')
    {
    $username = escapeInput($_POST['username']);
    $password = escapeInput($_POST['password']);
    var_dump($username);
    $password = sha1($password, true);
    $login = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password'";
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$login);
    $user = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_NUM);
    if($user[0]) {
        echo '<div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">Successfuly logged in.</div>';
        // Store Session Data
        $_SESSION['username'] = $username;  // Initializing Session with value of PHP Variable
        header("Location: home.php");
        die();                    
    }
    else echo '<div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">Incorrect username and/or password.</div>';
    }
}
```

Comment: can you add the code with `mysqli_real_escape_string()` that returns `NULL`

Comment: Are you passing DB connection to that function as the first parameter? If you weren't connected, you'd see `echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();` - Show more related code.

Comment: If you don't have any error in the mysqli_connect_errno(); it won't show any error

Comment: You _must_ pass the connection `$con` as the first param to `mysqli_real_escape_string()`. MySQLi does not work as a drop-in replacement for `mysql_*()` functions. So you'll need to get `$con` in scope of the `escapeInput()` function, by passing it as a parameter.

Comment: @ȿµŁƮɦąɲąŁŁąµȡƹƹɲ That actually isn't the case for `mysqli_connect_error()`, which is intended to be used right after attempting to connect (when you may not have an object to pass in). It _is_ true of `mysqli_error()` though.

Comment: Just as I thought; as per my original comment. Pass DB connection to that function.

Comment: Make sure you enable PHP's error display, _always_ when developing code. You would see PHP complaining about an invalid parameter to `mysqli_real_escape_string()`.  At the top of your script: `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: As a design point though, I would skip the `stripslashes()` and `htmlspecialchars()` in the `escapeInput()` function. (trim() is ok).  You should have no need for `stripslashes()` unless code is inconsistently escaping values elsewhere.  The `htmlspecialchars()` should be used at the time of _output_ rather than on your stored data, so that the values you store are not modified from their original form.

Comment: *"using `mysqli_real_escape_string()`"* - `mysqli_escape_string($data)`? Use just that `mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $var)` - Better yet; use [**prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). You won't have to fiddle with all that. Plus, I hope you're not storing passwords in plain text.

Comment: Show your HTML form. Plus, you overwrote your original code using `mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $data)` without marking it as an **edit**. Those are called/known as *Stealth edits*.

Comment: I didn't know about this . Anyway mysqli_escape_string() is an alias of mysqli_real_escape_string() .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reality is if you want to code a login page these days you shouldn't be using deprecated code. You should look in to PDO. I made the jump and it sounded scary at first but it was one of the best things I ever did. It's as simple as this.

```
$Qry = $db->prepare("SELECT COUNT(username) FROM users WHERE username = :User AND password = Pass");
$Qry->execute(array(':User'=>$username, ':Pass'=>$password));
```

Then you can use

```
$Qry->rowCount();
```

You'll have to change your connection string but it's much more secure and future friendly

[Prepared Statements](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php-database-access-are-you-doing-it-correctly--net-25338)

Answer (score 2):

`mysqli_real_escape_string()` requires two parameters:

1. A connection resource (created by calling `mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);`)
2. A string.

z`mysqli_real_escape_string()` always returns `null` when the first parameter is `null`. Therefore, make sure that you have created a connection object and that you have not yet closed it with `mysqli_close()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`$data = mysqli_escape_string($con, $data);`

You need to pass your connection object as first parameter.

Comment: It still returns NULL

Comment: I have a simmilar case.
My code works perfectly in fpm mode, but returns `NULL` in cli mode.